# How to Set an if in css for opera browser?

Tags: css, opera

How can have a custom css file for just opera browser ?

Something like IF IE.

I want to have a special one for opera.

Comment: In this case I would always to see if you cannot adapt your CSS to make it work cross-browser. Can you give the CSS which does not work for Opera and you have to resort to CSS hacks and filters? Also what Opera version did you test for?

Comment: you can use the @support querie using any prefixed CSS3 , give us a fiddle to play with and show you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use the `-o-prefocus`hack test this in a opera browser to see the difference

```
<p>HELLO WORLD</p>

p { font-size: 20px;  }
-o-prefocus, p{
       font-size: 90px;
}
```